# Format a word (make it red) with a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, format

Not a dupe... Non of mentioned work.. 
Trying to highlight a word with a google extension. Running this as a content script, but it doesn't seem to be a working solution... What have I missed?

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace("Target Text", "<font color='red'>Target Text</font>");

            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line you're asking for the child nodes of a node:

```
 var node = element.childNodes[j];
```

This will always return an array of nodes, even if there's only one node.
So this condition will never be true:

```
if (node.nodeType === 3)
```

You're actually getting all `nodes` and you'll have to loop over those as well.

Comment: Well, actually it does work, but not the html code... It doesn'n make it red, but just replacing the word on the page with the code without format"<font color='red'>Target Text</font>"

Comment: @JessicaRay You probably want to set the innerHTML and not the text of the node.

Comment: Yes, @Nate, u r right... Thank you.